# Angularjs angular / angular-tooltips

Tags: angularjs, tooltip

I'm using the tooltip module https://github.com/720kb/angular-tooltips but when i set content in the tooltip-template i getting the lexer error.

> Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 14-14 [ż] in expression [somt text in polish lang].

This error only appear when I use sentences like "Somthing like this". If string is without spaces / spacial chars the error does not show up.

Comment: Angularjs version is 1.3.15

Comment: Can you re-produce this defect in jsfiddle?